# Sign up using Facebook redirecting to Google OAuth page

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I am not logged in, in any question page, if I click on add comment link, It asks for login listing login providers. When I click "sign up using facebook", it takes me to Google Oauth page.

Elsewhere, the facebook login is working fine. Only in add comment login form, facebook signin it has a bug.

**EDIT**: I see this problem across entire stackexchange network, not just for stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing it. Working it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oof, good find. I have patched this up and we'll be doing a prod build ASAP to push the fix out. Thanks for identifying this!